# How to skip code if created dataset has zero rows

Tags: sas

I have a job which at first imports some xlsx files, then connects to multiple DB tables.  Based on conditions, the job selects rows to output, and creates an excel file to send on to the final end-user.

Sometimes, that job returns zero rows, which is acceptable; in that case, I would prefer to create an empty excel file with only the variables, but not run the other code (checking/cleaning code).

How can I conditionally execute code only when there are results?

Something like this:

```
I get 0 rows

If Result = 0 then Go to *"here"*
Else *"just run the code further"*
```

Comment: Did you try using macro logic?  `%IF ... %THEN %DO; ... %END;`?

Comment: I think it's generally okay to ask a question about technique - which this one is - when it's well written and focused, without having tried the common technique.  (I'm not sure if you're just asking for clarification, or suggesting OP should've done more homework or something, but wanted to clarify how I feel about that.)  Good and interesting question, other than the formatting which I'll fix in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few useful things that can help you here.

First off, `PROC SQL` sets a macro variable `SQLOBS`, which is particularly useful in identifying how many records were returned from the *last* SQL query it ran.

```
proc sql;
  select * from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put I returned &SQLOBS rows;
```

You might use this to drive further processing, either with `%IF` blocks as Tom notes in comments or other methods I will cover below.

You can also check how many rows are in a dataset *explicitly*, if you prefer a slightly more robust option.

```
proc sql;
  select count(*) into :class_count from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put I returned &class_count rows;
```

For very large datasets, there are faster options (using the dataset descriptors, dictionary tables, or a few other options), but for most tables this is fine.

Either way, what I would typically do with a program I intended to run in *production* would be then to drive the rest of the program from macros.

```
%macro whatIWantToDo(params);
...
do stuff
...
%mend whatIWantToDo;

proc sql;
  mySqlStuff;
quit;

%if &sqlobs. gt 0 %then %do;
  %whatIWantToDo(params);
%end;
%else %do;
  %put Nothing to do;
%end;
```

Another option is to use `call execute`; this is appropriate if your data drives the macro parameters.  The big advantage of `call execute` is that it only runs if you have data rows - if you have zero, it won't do anything!

Say you have some datasets to run code on.  You could have up to twelve - one per month - but only have them for the current calendar year, so in Jan you have one, Feb you have two, etc.  You could do this:

```
data mydata_jan mydata_feb mydata_mar;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

%macro printit(data=);
  title "Printing &data.";
  proc print data=&data;
  run;
  title;
%mend printit;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.vtable;
  where upcase(memname) like 'MYDATA_%' and nobs gt 0;
  callstr = cats('%printit(data=',memname,')');
  call execute(Callstr);
run;
```

First I make the datasets, with a name I can programmatically identify.  Then I make the macro that I want to run on each (this could be checking, cleaning, whatever).  Then I use `sashelp.vtable` which shows which tables are created, and check the `nobs` variable (number of observations) is more than zero.  Then I use `call execute` to run the macro on that dataset!